# Can high server's CPU usage cause high ping for clients?

Tags: central-processing-unit, ping, cpu-usage, latency

Some users have high ping and they cannot play my multiplayer game due to it. My server application is causing CPU to always rise little by little and when I restart it, it drops. I am working on fixing it, but wondering now, can CPU usage be related to this ping issue? I know CPU isn't really responsible for sending and receiving packets, is it?

Answer (score 2):

What OS and platform does the server run on?

By "ping" do you mean ICMP echo, or latency in your protocol?

In general, yes, the network stack is a part of the OS and runs on the CPU. However, that doesn't necessarily mean it corresponds to your problem.

Try and measure latency on a different system as close to the server as possible. If the problem goes away in the same datacenter, it might be the problem client's network providers on the path to you.